# Securing a toilet flange on top of ceramic tile

Tags: toilet, flange

Most suggest that a toilet flange sit on top of tile so that the bottom of the flange is flush with the ceramic tile.  If that is so, how is the flange attached to to subfloor as the flange holes will be over the tile?

I’m hoping to avoid trying to drill hole through the time for the anchor screws.

Comment: You really don't have much option but to drill (I'd recommend a diamond tipped bit and keep the area flushed with water to cool the bit).

Comment: I'm in the minority according to your findings, but I fit tile around the flange. It can sit on the tile substrate and easily be screwed into the subfloor. Wax rings have plenty of squish to handle that.

Answer (score 1):

I see very many toilets fixed down with only silicone sealant and blank plastic plugs in the fastening holes. One was in a home owned by a guy who weighed in at 400lbs (30 stone or 190kgs)...

I've also struggled to remove toilets fixed in such a way!

I wonder if this may be a national issue though, as I'm not quite sure what you mean when you say toilet 'flange'. We call them a toilet 'pan' and they have one or two holes each side at the bottom for screws, often going into a plastic bracket inside the base.